# tvOS: Creating parallax effect on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, tvos

I'm using iOS 9 Storyboards to create a tvOS app.

The app has a UICollectionView. I've defined an Apple TV image stack that contains a Front, Middle and Back asset in my Assets.xcassets collection.

When a user highlights a UICollectionViewCell, I'd like to have a have a 'highlight' effect similar to what the app icon has, where a user can 'circle' their finger on the Siri remote to expose the parallax effect and shine.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: FYI there is a parallax previewer on apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/tvos/download/ there's plenty on youtube of how to use this too.

Comment: We created controls and extensions that can be used to easly add parallax effect to any UIView github.com/PGSSoft/ParallaxView

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just found an answer. Hope this helps someone else:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CameraCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = [_cameras objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = YES;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 853, 560);
    [cell addSubview:imageView];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest [cell.contentView addsubView:ImageView] in general, in case you want to take advantage of the two UICollectionViewCell backgroundView properties.